# helm test failure: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We have a simple release test for a `Redis` chart. After running `helm test myReleaseName --tls --cleanup`, we got

```
RUNNING: myReleaseName-redis
ERROR: timed out waiting for the condition
```

There are several issues in Github repository at https://github.com/helm/helm/search?q=timed+out+waiting+for+the+condition&type=Issues but I did not find a solution to it.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This first looks puzzling and shows little information because `--cleanup` will kill the pods after running. One can remove it to get more information. I, thus, reran the test with

```
helm test myReleaseName --tls --debug
```

Then use `kubectl get pods` to examine the pod used for testing. (It could be of other names.)

```
NAME                                                 READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AG
myReleaseName-redis                                            0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          12h
```

From here, it is more clear now that there is something wrong with images, and it turned out that **the link used to pull the image is not correct**. (Use `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>` and then you can find the link you used to pull the image.)

Fix the link, and it worked.

Comment: `--tls` is not longer valid parameter.

Answer (score 11):

For me, helm couldn't pull the image as it was in private repo

`kubectl get events` helped me get the logs.

```
9m38s       Warning   Failed              pod/airflow-scheduler-bbd8696bf-5mfg7      Failed to pull image
```

After authenticating, helm install command worked.

REF: https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/11904

Comment: Helm timeout is a generic error. Checking the events would help understand and translate the issue.

Answer (score 7):

if `helm test <ReleaseName> --debug` shows installation completed successfully but deployment failed, may be because of deployment takes more than 300 sec.

Helm will wait as long as what is set with --timeout . By default, the timeout is set to 5min, sometimes for many reason helm install may take extra time to deploy, so increase the timeout value and validate the installation.

`helm install <ReleaseName> --debug --wait --timeout 30m`

Comment: This is great advice, but a helm timeout is usually due to the pod in the cluster that helm deployed the app to is failing to start. Connect to the cluster, and use "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces" to see the status of all pods and determine if the pod is not starting or repeated restarting (e.g. crashLoop Backoff) - which would cause the timeout.

Comment: Some pods can take longer time to start up. It doesn't mean that the pod is having issues if it's not starting up in the period of 5 minutes. It could be also that it just takes a little longer than that.